# How to append consecutive values in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, cursor

I am not able to append the current value of @msg with the newest values. It is ok with the 1st @msg as it prints out all values but when it comes to 2nd @msg, it returns only the latest value. I have an idea to create a temporary table for storing newest values. What would you suggest in this situation?

```
FETCH NEXT FROM c_fileList INTO @dbName, @filename
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
         SET @msg = 'Delete backup file: ' + @filename + ' For Database: ' + @dbName 
         PRINT @msg
         FETCH NEXT FROM c_fileList INTO @dbName, @filename
   END
   PRINT @msg
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your needs... Please try to create a [mcve]. In this case I'd be enough to add a temp table's DDL, two or three sample rows and the expected output...

Answer (score 1):

`SET @msg = 'Delete...'` doesn't concatenate the value for `@msg`, it reassigns it. if you want to concatenate the value, it would be `SET @msg = @msg + 'Delete...'`.

Seems like this would be much easier with `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` though. A Cursor is an awfully slow way to make what is effectively a delimited list.

```
DECLARE @msg nvarchar(4000);

SET @msg = STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(10) +
                         N'Delete backup file: ' + {FileName Column} + N' for Database: ' + {DBName Column}
                  FROM YourTable
                  --ORDER BY ???
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(4000)'),1,1,N'');

PRINT @Msg;
```

As should already be obvious, this will truncate any value longer than 4,000 characters (which is the max length for a `PRINT`).

Answer (score 0):

if my assumption about what you're trying to accomplish, and how you're doing it, is correct, you don't need a cursor or a temp table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempFiles', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempFiles

CREATE TABLE #tempFiles
(
    RecordID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
    , DBName VARCHAR(32)
    , DBFileName VARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO #tempFiles VALUES
('DBOne', 'c:\DBOnefileone.mdf')
, ('DBOne', 'c:\DBOnefiletwo.mdf')
, ('DBOne', 'c:\DBOnefilethree.mdf')
, ('DBOne', 'c:\DBOnelogfileone.ldf')
, ('DBTwo', 'c:\DBTwofileone.mdf')
, ('DBTwo', 'c:\DBTwologfileone.ldf')

DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @msg = @msg + 'Delete backup file: ' + DBFileName + ' For Database: ' + DBName + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM    #tempFiles
ORDER BY RecordID

print @msg
```

Comment: The *quirky update* is a slippery slope ... I don't know if the sort order matters...